# How to get unique records of attributes fetched by includes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, group-by, include

I fetch some associated results like

```
all_makes = CarMake.includes(:car_models).group('name')
```

Now what I need to get only unique by name car_models

```
all_makes_json = all_makes.as_json

all_makes.each_with_index do |make,index|
  all_makes_json[index]["models"] = make.car_models.uniq {|e| e[:name] }
end
```

But this not working. How can I get only unique records in this scenario?

Comment: `make.car_models.uniq! {|e| e[:name] }` modifies `make.car_models`; try dropping the `bang!` method for `uniq`, though, for optimal performance, you should be doing this in your database.

Comment: Tried but that also not working

Comment: Could you post the schema, an example of data and expected result? It will help others to identify your expectation better.

Comment: `.includes` will by default load in two queries and there is no way really to control the second query which just loads all the associated records. If you use references to force a single query the group clause will make it so that only one car_model per row is returned. Its not the right approach at all.